# How to bind empty numeric field to default value 0 in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have some numeric fields(but not compulsory) in my jsp form 
eg. kkqty, sogoqty and sesaqty.
so when user not giving any input in those fields I m receiving Null at my controller side hence getting null property exception while saving these form data

**My POJO (OutletInfo.java)**

```
 private Double kkqty;
 private Double sogoqty;
 private Double sesaqty;

//getter & setters

@Column(name = "KKqty", nullable = false, precision = 10)
public Double getKkqty() {
    return this.kkqty;
}

public void setKkqty(Double kkqty) {
    this.kkqty = kkqty;
}

@Column(name = "sogoqty", nullable = false, precision = 10)
public Double getSogoqty() {
    return this.sogoqty;
}

public void setSogoqty(Double sogoqty) {
    this.sogoqty = sogoqty;
}

@Column(name = "sesaqty", nullable = false, precision = 10)
public Double getSesaqty() {
    return this.sesaqty;
}
```

**My Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "saveOutletInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveOutletInfo(OutletInfo outletInfo,HttpServletRequest request){

    System.out.print("KKQTY:"+outletInfo.getKkqty());               
    return this.getMasterService().saveOutletInfo(outletInfo);      
}
```

In controller when I m trying to print all numeric fields , I am receiving null here,hence not able to save .

I need to convert instead of null to default value 0.0
one way I know that i need to check all fields if null then set it to 0.0 but this is pretty much hard coded ,so i want automatic conversion in this scenario.

I gone through some post and came across about @InitBinder but i m unable to use it in such case.

somthing like

@InitBinder
     public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Double.class, new CustomNumberEditor(Double.class, true));
     }

can anyone suggest how i can automatically convert to all my numeric fields to 0.0 when it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a global init-binder, something like

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalBindingInitializer {

 /* global InitBinder  */

 @InitBinder
 public void binder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.registerCustomEditor(Double.class, new CustomDoubleEditor());
 }
}
```

and register the following editor

```
public class CustomDoubleEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    public CustomDoubleEditor() {
    }

    public String getAsText() {
        Double d = (Double) getValue();
        return d.toString();
    }

    public void setAsText(String str) {
        if (str == "" || str == null)
            setValue(0);
        else
            setValue(Double.parseDouble(str));
    }
}
```

however, in your context, a more appropriate solution seems to be to simply initialize the instance variables or set a default constructor to the value of 0

```
private Double kkqty = 0.0;
private Double sogoqty = 0.0;
private Double sesaqty = 0.0;
```

Comment: I tried initializing like this but still i m getting null .

Comment: but the use of  @InitBinder you suggested is working great.....thanks a lot. :) :)

Comment: how to convert collections?